# setfillstyle not working in c graphics while compiles on ubuntu

Tags: c, bgi

while writing c graphics program (in ubuntu ) setfillstyle not working.

```
   setfillstyle(1,RED);
   circle(50,100,5);
   floodfill(51,101,WHITE);
```

getting error as

```
/tmp/ccps2Qkp.o: In function `main':
demo.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `setfillstyle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

full code as follows

```
#include<graphics.h> 
int main()
{
   int gd = DETECT,gm;
   initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);

   setfillstyle(1,RED);
   circle(50,100,5);
   floodfill(51,101,WHITE); 

   delay(50000);
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is clear: you're not linking libraries required for the API you're using. Are you using [Boss](http://www.codedread.com/boss.php) ?

Comment: Was your program supposed to work on Turbo C++ intially?

Comment: yes. its worked but not in ubuntu

Comment: **ubuntu** is not **MS-DOS** !!! ... `graphics.h` is ancient **Borland BGI** api for **MS-DOS** so either use **MS-DOS** or emulator ... there are also windows ports like WinBGI but I do not know of any for **linux**.... To make BGI work you also need a proper gfx BGI driver at accessible location ...  If you are not bound to **BGI** do not use it ...